# css controling font size in HTML EMAILS

Tags: css, html-email, font-size

**Is there a way to keep fonts to a similar size in HTML EMAILS?**

On the Website it looks great but in my email the text is very small and close together.

[Live Demo](http://EdVizenor.com/rosary/email/HailMary.php)

I am including a screen shot of what I see in my email.[image]

Any way to fix this?

**Here is the html code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>The Most Holy Rosary</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
#Table_01 tr td #box {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (Holy Mary Email copy.psd) -->
<table width="843" height="855" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Table_01">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top">
            <img src="http://www.EdVizenor.com/rosary/email/images/HailMary_01.png" width="546" height="253" alt=""></td>
        <td width="297" rowspan="3" valign="top">
            <img src="http://www.EdVizenor.com/rosary/email/images/HailMary_02.png" width="297" height="855" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="11" valign="top">
            <img src="http://www.EdVizenor.com/rosary/email/images/HailMary_03.png" width="11" height="565" alt=""></td>
        <td width="535" valign="top"><table width="95%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="15" id="box">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top"><p style="font-weight: bold; color: #666;">PRAISE BE JESUS CHRIST!</p>
            <p><br>
              Thank you for taking the time to read this email. We are developing some exciting media to help you and others fall even more in love with JESUS through the power of Mary, the Queen of Heaven (Revelations 12) and through Heaven's blessed gift to us... The Most Holy Rosary. </p>
            <p>We need your help if you can. We need you to answer some quick questions on the Rosary. Also once on the page can you &quot;like&quot; it on Facebook, Tweet it and finally forward this email to friends who may be interested. Awesome! Thank you so much.</p>
            <p align="center"><a href="http://www.EdVizenor.com/?p=questions"><img src="http://www.EdVizenor.com/rosary/email/images/HolyRosary.png" width="364" height="67"></a></p>
            <p>Be assured of my prayers for you and all your intentions in my Rosary.</p>
            <p>In The Merciful Heart Of Jesus Christ,<br>
            <span style="color: #666">Ed Vizenor </span></p></td>
          </tr>
      </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top">
            <img src="http://www.EdVizenor.com/rosary/email/images/HailMary_05.png" width="546" height="37" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some mail clients will change the font if the text is inside of a `<td>` tag. So you would need to repeat this for each of your table cells: `<td style="line-height: 25px; font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:16px">...</td>`. Hope that helps someone landing here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Always give  **inline styling** for the emails. Emails not support external styling. Write like this:

```
<table style="font-size:16px" width="843" height="855" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
```

Comment: I've found the [Premailer](https://github.com/alexdunae/premailer) library to be very convenient for doing this.

Comment: OK I put it in a table that contains main text. Still didn't work: <table width="95%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="15" id="box"  style="line-height: 25px; font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:16px">

Comment: This code will work may be there something else creating problem on it. For good practice check some email codes in your gmail etc.

Answer (score 3):

For email put all your font css inline in font tags, span tags or in the `<td>` containing your text.

```
<font style="color:#770000;">This will always work</font>
```

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="color:#770000;">
      So will this.  
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am posting the code that worked. I did the "INLINE STYLES" on the table but it didn't work so I put 'INLINE STYLES" on all the paragraphs. It looks good in my email client.

Only ONE small issue and that is the image on the left, the left bar next to white space for text, is like one pixel off in gmail. Can't fix that bugger.

Ok here is the code that works

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Holy Mary Email copy</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (Holy Mary Email copy.psd) -->
<table width="843" height="855" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Table_01">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top">
            <img src="http://www.EdVizenor.com/rosary/email/images/HailMary_01.png" width="546" height="253" alt=""></td>
        <td width="297" rowspan="3" valign="top">
            <img src="http://www.EdVizenor.com/rosary/email/images/HailMary_02.png" width="297" height="855" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="11" valign="top">
            <img src="http://www.EdVizenor.com/rosary/email/images/HailMary_03.png" width="11" height="565" alt=""></td>
        <td width="535" valign="top"><table width="95%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="box">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top"><p style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #666; font-size: 17px">PRAISE BE JESUS CHRIST!</p>
              <p><span style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 17px">Thank you for taking the time to read this email. We are developing some exciting media to help you and others fall even more in love with JESUS through the power of Mary, the Queen of Heaven (Revelations 12) and through Heaven's blessed gift to us... The Most Holy Rosary. <br>
                <br>
                </span><span style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 17px">We need your help if you can. We need you to answer some quick questions on the Rosary. Also once on the page can you &quot;like&quot; it on Facebook, Tweet it and finally forward this email to friends who may be interested? Awesome! Thank you so much.</span></p>
              <span style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 17px">
                <p align="center"><a href="http://www.EdVizenor.com/?p=questions"><img src="http://www.EdVizenor.com/rosary/email/images/HolyRosary.png" alt="" width="364" height="67"></a></p>
              </span>
              <p><span style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 17px">Be assured of my prayers for you and all your intentions in my Rosary.</span></p>
              <p><span style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 17px">In The Merciful Heart Of Jesus Christ,</span><br>
                <span style="color: #666">Ed Vizenor </span> </td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top">
            <img src="http://www.EdVizenor.com/rosary/email/images/HailMary_05.png" width="546" height="37" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

there!
To avoid this problem with spacing between images in Gmail (which occurs in Hotmail as well), you have to put  `display=block` as an inline CSS style in your images. Just like that:

```
img src="http://webserver.com/image.jpeg" alt="" style="display:block;"
```